# How could second-order logic satisfy (neo) Fregean's epistemic goal?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

Recently I've been reading Shapiro's Higher Order Logic in The Oxford Handbook of Philosophy of Mathematics and Logic, Chapter 25. There are some paragraphs confusing me:

> One traditional goal of logical study is to present a calculus, a deductive system that represents the canons of correct inference. The idea is that a given proposition Φ is a consequence of a set Γ only if it is possible to justify Φ on the basis of Γ alone. This conception of logic is behind the Fregean goal of giving proofs of various mathematical propositions that are free of gaps (see chapters 5–6 of the present volume). No intuition and no empirical, or otherwise substantial, knowledge should be required in proving theorems on the basis of premises or axioms.  […]   The fact is that the model-theoretic consequence relation of second- or higher-order logic with standard semantics does not meet this traditional goal of providing a calculus. For one thing, standard-validity is defined in terms of models, not inference patterns. Of course, that much applies to any model-theoretic system, including that of first-order languages and second-order languages with Henkin semantics. In those cases, however, a completeness theorem links the model-theoretic consequence relation with the deductive one, and this provides a connection with the epistemic goal of codifying correct inference patterns. In contrast, the incompleteness of second-order logic shows that the consequence relation of second-order logic, with standard semantics, is highly noneffective (section 4.2 above). Any effective deductive system is either unsound (in that it sanctions an invalid argument) or fails to codify at least one valid argument.

In my opinion, once SOL cannot determine semantic validity through deductive calculus (provide gap-free proofs for theorem providing), then it must be rejected by Neo-Fregeans. But Neo-Fregeans like Wright never seem to give any justification of why second-order logic is still able to satisfy the Fregean epistemic goal. How can it be an innocent epistemological source, while there is no completeness theorem that links model-theoretic consequences relation with the deductive one, and we have to go back to set theory to determine logical validity?

Comment: Shapiro is an ardent mathematical structuralist and hold truth/meaning absolutism views similar to those of Frege and Zermelo, contrast to relativism views such as those espoused by Skolem and Von Neumann. So naturally even SOL with standard semantics is incomplete, (neo) Fregeans use it to its fullest expressive power, not to mention they can use its multi-sorted FOL version for many cases (Henkin model like 2nd-order arithmetic's base theory RCA0). In summary (neo) Fregeans mainly pursue absolute truths involving higher order levels in a non-ideal way, but not necessarily all truths...

Comment: Simply, no solution currently available... We have two different approach: semantical validity and deductive inference based on rules "mechanically" applicable. The first one is as old as logic itself (see Aristotle), The second one is of paramount relevance today: theorem provers, etc. And then there is the issue of "expressive capability": FOL is limited (relevant for some part of mathematics ?) and HOL seems the "good" solution, but...